# Displaying actual land area on map

Tags: reactjs, plotly, plotly-dash

for a Python Dash Dashboard I'm building right now it would be cool to have a way to represent given values of land area on a map. Like for example a dot which is 50km^2 big on a map.

Unfortunately Chloropleth maps and all the other things i tried only work with sizes relative from one marker to another, not relative to the map itself.

Does anyone know a possibility, maybe even outside of dash to implement this?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use the `Circle` component in dash-leaflet,

```
import dash
import dash_leaflet as dl

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = dl.Map([dl.Circle(center=(56, 10), radius=126),  # radius in meters
                     dl.TileLayer()], style={'width': '1000px', 'height': '500px'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

The `radius` is in meters, so `radius=126` will yield a circle with an area of about 50 km2.